# changing genemu jquery datepicker localization seetings won't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, symfony, localization, datepicker

I have installed genemu bundle for symfony with jquery datepicker and I am trying to change the localization seetings (to french) without any success.

I have followed all examples but nothing changes the datepicker language:
- I have jquery and jquery ui last versions loading in the header
- I have genemu installed correctly as the plugin actually loads
- I have registered the french regional settings from the jquery website and they are loaded as I can see when I make console.log($.datepicker.regional); This prints [Object, en: Object, en-US: Object, fr: Object] 
- I have tempted to apply this french config by different ways :

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
$(".datepicker").datepicker("option",$.datepicker.regional['fr']);
$(".datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional[""]);
```

- I have also tried to overwrite the defaults seetings from within the jquery ui file and I have no change which lets me suggest something else is overriding this.

I run out of ideas. Do you have any clue as to how to try to understand what is going wrong ?

in Symfony I have :

```
$builder->add('birthday', 'genemu_jquerydate', array(
                    'label'=>"Date de naissance",
                    'attr'=>['class'=>'datepicker'],
                    'widget' => 'single_text',
                    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'configs' => [
                        'changeMonth' => true,
                        'changeYear' => true,
                        'maxDate' => 0,
                    ],
                    'required' => false
                ))
```

In my view I have :

```
    {{ form(form,{'attr':{'action':path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'class':'fos_user_profile_edit'}}) }}

{{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
{{ form_javascript(form) }}
```

In my layout I have :

```
{% javascripts
'javascript/vendor/bootstrap-3.2.0.min.js'
'javascript/vendor/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js'
'javascript/vendor/jsTree/jstree.min.js'
filter='?yui_js'
%}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
<script>
    //        window.PixelAdmin.start(init);
    $(function(){
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
        console.log($.datepicker.regional);
        $(".datepicker").datepicker("option",$.datepicker.regional['fr']);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick.

I am using symfony and I had another bundle loading its own jquery depedencies after I was loading mine.

Therefore, I just had to remove this bundle and everything went fine.
I guess if the bundle is needed, there is just a need to remove the extra imported jquery library.